# Only output invalid YouTube ID's from database if video doesn't exists

Tags: php, mysqli

I have YouTube video IDs stored in my database. I'm trying to output the IDs that are only invalid. I'm using [get_headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) / [oembed](https://oembed.com/) which allows me to check if a video exists on YouTube. Then I am looping through the ID's. This is currently working but it's showing all YouTube IDs from my table and then adding the text "is invalid" to the ones that are invalid. I need to only display the ones that are invalid - nothing else!

I could use some help if anyone wouldn't mind. I would really appreciate it.

**Code:**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT src_id FROM youtube_videos ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 'Video ID: '.$row["src"];
    $headers = get_headers('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$row["src_id"].'');
    if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
        echo " is invalid";
    } else {
        echo "";
    }

    echo 'no results';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the video ID if the header code is not 200?

```php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $headers = get_headers('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$row["src_id"].'');
    if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
        echo "Video ID: ".$row['src']." is invalid\n";
    }
}
```

Might also want to look into a better way of grabbing response-headers, that thing might not be 100% accurate for all scenarios. I would suggest using something like

```php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $headers = get_headers('http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$row["src_id"].'');
    if (substr($headers[0], 9, 3) != 200) {
        echo "Video ID: ".$row['src']." is invalid\n";
    }
}
```